# Template function with std::map gives error: variable or field declared void

Tags: c++

Trying to create template function what couts the std::map elements, get this errors. I know what the map have four template arguments, but two have defaut values, cant understand what I have to do.

```
template<typename key, typename val> void arr_out (std::map<key, val>::iterator begin, std::map<key, val>::iterator end)
{
    std::cout << "map: " << std::endl;
    while(begin != end)
    {
        std::cout << (*begin).first << ": " << (*begin).second << std::endl ;
        begin++;
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

- error: variable or field ‘arr_out’ declared void
- error: expected ‘)’ before ‘begin’
- error: expected ‘)’ before ‘begin’

Comment: add a `typename` before `std::map<key,val>::` in both spots.

Comment: @AndyG There are still errors [even if you do that](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8281c1698a8bb346)

Comment: @Borgleader only if you rely on template argument deduction

Answer (score 5):

You should add typename keyword before each of template function arguments:

```
template<typename key, typename val> 
void arr_out (typename std::map<key, val>::iterator begin, 
              typename std::map<key, val>::iterator end)
```

Answer (score 2):

Add typename before iterator, it indicates that its nested value type of template.

```
template<typename key, typename val> 
void arr_out(typename std::map<key, val>::iterator begin, typename std::map<key, val>::iterator end)
{
    std::cout << "map: " << std::endl;
    while(begin != end)
    {
        std::cout << (*begin).first << ": " << (*begin).second << std::endl ;
        begin++;
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

to make code valid, you have to add `typename`,

```
template<typename key, typename val>
void arr_out (typename std::map<key, val>::iterator begin,
              typename std::map<key, val>::iterator end);
```

and as parameters are not deducible, call it:

```
std::map<Key, Value> m;
arr_out<Key, Value>(m.begin(), m.end());
```

An alternative to simplify call site is:

```
template <typename It>
void arr_out (It begin, It end);
```

or with some SFINAE:

```
template <typename It>
auto arr_out (It begin, It end)
-> decltype(void(std::cout << (*begin).first << (*begin).second));
```

Comment: Thx for tip with typename It ! I had to guess.

Answer (score 1):

The rules of template deduction don't allow you to infer `key` or `val` from `std::map<key, val>::iterator`.

The other answers tell you how to correct the definition, but you have to specify the type parameters when you use it.

```
int main()
{
    std::map<int, std::string> m;
    // arr_out(m.begin(), m.end()); // errors relating to template argument deduction
    arr_out<int, std::string>(m.begin(), m.end()); // Ok
    return 0;
}
```